# Enumerations in the database and O/RM

Tags: nhibernate, database-design, orm, enums, lookup-tables

Suppose I want entries in the table `Regions` to have a type, e.g. a city, a country etc. What's the accepted way of storing this type, assuming I'll be using O/RM (NHibernate in my case) ? I see two options:

- Have an enum in the C# bussines layer with the types and store the type as a `tinyint` in the table.
- Have a lookup table `RegionTypes` with the type identifiers (strings or ints) and reference them in the `Regions` table.

The second approach seems more reasonable from the database point of view, since I have foreign key constraints, plus I can have additional data about the region types, e.g. a city is a child type for country (and since I'm using SQL Server 2008 spatial features, I actually need this information for spatial manipulations). However, looking from the C# point of view, I'll basically have to have an entity `RegionType` and load it from the database every time i want to assign it to a region (as I understand NHibernate wouldn't allow me to make the type an enum if I store it in a lookup table). This is a little tedious for such a simple task, knowing that region types are basically fixed and unlikely to change.

What about other types, like `DayOfWeek` which are unlikely to ever change or have additional properties, should they have their lookup tables and entities ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule is to use **Enum**s if you are sure that set of values will never be changed **by user**. Otherwise it's better to use lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

One reason to use lookup tables is the common use case of displaying the possible values in a menu or something.  It's easy to query a lookup table, but less easy if the enum is hard-coded in a database data type or constraint, or in a C# enum.

Answer (score 0):

I usually go with the latter option, though, I'll create a generic sort of set up where items of multiple types can be stored in the same table so that I don't end up with 15 types tables. The basics are something like this

```
Types
   TypeID int,
   Name varchar(20),
   Description varchar(100)

Type_Items
   ItemID int,
   TypeID int -> Types.TypeID,
   Name varchar(20),
   Description varchar(100),
   Value varchar(100)
```

Comment: This would be a good and valid lookup/reference system, but completely invalid insofar as database relational integrity is concerned.

Comment: You would not be able to set up a foreign key constraint "into" the lookup table, unless the full primary key (Type + Id) were present in *both* parent and child table. RDBMSs are very good at enforcing relational integrity, and I'd hate to lose that buit-in functionality.

Comment: @Philip: Some degree of referential integrity can still be maintained. Still, if it's that important to you, an extra field in a table is far easier to maintain than an extra 20 or 30 tables in my opinion.

Comment: What's the problem with having 20 or 30 tables?  I know in Oracle it's a chore to allocate space for a new table, but that's because it's dinosaur technology from the 1980's.

Comment: @Bill: If they're necessary there's nothing wrong with 20 or 30 tables. If they're not necessary they just make the database design more complex.